# Three.js ERROR during additional components importing

Tags: javascript, three.js

I am working on a project where I need to develop a simple 1 HTML web application with 3D graphics. I decided to use Three.js, but there is a problem, I am really confused about how to make imports. While running examples everything seems to work, but when I try to implement the same ideas in my code I keep getting all sorts of errors.

My problem is that I am not willing to use tons of different frameworks and additional libraries, I want to keep things simple and use just node js and express for the webserver and pure HTML, CSS, and JS (with Three.js) for the front end, for Three.js I found [this](https://unpkg.com/three@0.119.0/) public CDN.

So now where the problem comes in, in code I am trying importing Three.js things like that:

```js
import * as THREE from "https://unpkg.com/three@0.119.0/build/three.module.js";
import { OrbitControls } from "https://unpkg.com/three@0.119.0/examples/jsm/controls/OrbitControls.js";
```

and code works absolutly fine with older versions (< **0.128.0**) but after **0.127.0** release for some reason imports are no longer relative:

**Older version (0.127.0)**:

```
// https://unpkg.com/three@0.127.0/examples/jsm/controls/OrbitControls.js
import {
  ...
} from '../../../build/three.module.js';
```

**Newest version (0.130.0)**:

```
// https://unpkg.com/three@0.130.0/examples/jsm/controls/OrbitControls.js
import {
  ...
} from 'three';
```

and with newer versions I get following error:

*TypeError: Failed to resolve module specifier "three". Relative references must start with either "/", "./", or "../".*

**What am I doing wrong and is it even possible to use these new version with CDN?**

*Comple code can be found [here](https://github.com/dk731/cube2)*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/wiki/Migration-Guide#127--128

- NPM: ES6 modules in examples/jsm now import using the bare specifier
  three. This change breaks working with modules in cdns such as
  https://www.jsdelivr.com/ and https://unpkg.com/. Please use
  https://www.skypack.dev/ instead.